# Looping through data and dynamically storing it in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

Currently, I am starting out with an empty array, `reportSections`. I am then looping through the values of `date group` and `record date` and add the unique values into my `reportSections` array.

```
let reportSections = [];
    let dataGroups = new Set();
    let recordDates = new Set();
    data.forEach(item => {
      dataGroups.add(item['date group']);
      recordDates.add(item['record date']);
    });
    for (const [index, value] of [...dataGroups].entries())
      reportSections.push({
        id: value,
        name: [...recordDates][index]
      });
```

Here is a small example what the data looks like inside the `data` variable that I will be looping through:

```
[
  {
     'record date': '2020-04-01',
     'date group': 'MONTH START'
  },
  {
     'record date': '2020-04-01',
     'date group': 'MONTH START'
  },
  {
     'record date': '2020-04-05',
     'date group': 'MONTH TO DATE - Week 1'
  },
  {
     'record date': '2020-04-05',
     'date group': 'MONTH TO DATE - Week 1'
  }
]
```

However, now I need to do something very similar to three other parts of my code, but it's a bit different setup since the values need added to objets instead of an array and therefore cannot use the push() method. Here is what the current code looks like:

```
let filteredData = {
    monthstart: _.filter(data, {'date group': 'MONTH START'}),
    monthstart_week1: _.filter(data, {'date group': 'MONTH TO DATE - Week 1'}),
    monthstart_week2: _.filter(data, {'date group': 'MONTH TO DATE - Week 2'}),
  };

  let combinedData = {
    monthstart: [],
    monthstart_week1: [],
    monthstart_week2: [],
  };

  let reportMap = {
    monthstart: {},
    monthstart_week1: {},
    monthstart_week2: {},
  };
```

Normally I have this hardcoded, but since I will be dealing with dynamic dates and there can be a different number of weeks in a given month, I need to have something dynamic on my end. **My question is, how can I loop through the data and display each unique `date group` in `filteredData`, `combinedData`, and `reportMap` as I did for my `reportSections` array?**

Sidenote:

The empty arrays and objects within `combinedData` and `reportMap` would stay just as they are, with only the actual name changing (ie `monthstart` would change dynamically but `[]` or `{}` would not. With `filteredData`, the name would change as well (ie `monthstart`) and I would also need the same value from `date group` to be used in the `_.filter()` part.

I hope I was able to explain this clearly enough. If I need to explain more, just let me know and I can add more detail to my question, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to dynamically add new key-value pair to the object.

You can do it like that:

```js
const myObject = {};
// loop start
  myObject["myDynamicKey"] = "myDynamicValue";
// loop end
```

or like this, using spread operator:

```js
let myObject = {};
// loop start
  myObject = {...myObject, ["myDynamicKey"]: "myDynamicValue"}
// loop end
```

Comment: This is awesome! I used this within the for loop that I had for my `reportSections` array and it worked just as I needed it to! Thank you so much!